# Trying to pass Bokeh Wordcloud2 to Django Templete

Tags: django, django-templates, bokeh, word-cloud, wordcloud2

I am working on passing data visualization using Bokeh library to Django project. I am able to pass standard Bokeh visualization but when I am trying to used an external wordcloud2 library my project crashes. I receive message "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator." Any ideas would be much appreciated?!

Imports used:

```
        from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
        from bokeh.embed import components
        # Bokeh WordCloud
        from bokeh.io import show
        from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
        from bokeh_wordcloud2 import WordCloud2
```

**views.py**

Code below is working:

```
        x = [1,2,3,4,5]
        y = [1,2,3,4,5]

        plot = figure(title='Line Graph', x_axis_label='x_stuff', y_axis_label='y_stuff', plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
        plot.line(x, y, line_width=2)

        #auto_div - dynamically generates div elemetent
        script, auto_div = components(plot)
```

Based on example above, I am trying to pass values for wordcloud in very similar way but it is not working:

```
        titles = ['lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
                'consectetur adipiscing elit',
                'cras iaculis semper odio',
                'eu posuere urna vulputate sed']
        test1 = ColumnDataSource({'titles':titles})  
        wordcloud = WordCloud2(source=test1,wordCol="titles",color=['pink','blue','green']) 

        script, auto_div = components(wordcloud)

        context = {
            'script':script,
            'auto_div':auto_div,
        }

        return render(request, 'two_boxes/home.html', context)
```

Based on my testing it seems like the problem occurs at `script, auto_div = components(wordcloud)` statement

**home.html**

```
        <head>
        {% block bokeh_dependencies %}
        <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.3.4.min.css" rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css”>
        <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.3.4.min.css" rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css”>

        <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
        {{ script | safe }}
        {% endblock %}
        </head>

        <body>
        <h1>Bokeh Stuff</h1>
        {{ auto_div | safe }}
        </body>
```

Resources:

https://hackernoon.com/integrating-bokeh-visualisations-into-django-projects-a1c01a16b67a
https://github.com/joranbeasley/bokeh_wordcloud2

Comment: After digging a little deeper it seems that the wordcloud2 library itself has some issues. If anyone decides to try the working example I would recommend to comment out `from bokeh_wordcloud2 import WordCloud2`

Comment: what should that line be replaced with?